# Use alias and add variable together

Tags: linux, curl, alias

I found nice command to check whether in terminal:

```
curl wttr.in/
```

By adding after slash city name it will show whether in typed place for example:

```
curl wttr.in/NewYork
```

There is need to simplify this command using alias but then it appear a problem with variable after alias.

```
alias yyy="curl wttr.in/"
```

There is error trying to use alias with variable in terminal:

```
yyy NewYork
```

How manage to use alias with variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function and use it the same way you use an alias

```
function yyy() { curl wttr.in/${1}; }

yyy NewYork
```